# Record not deleting using php/ajax

Tags: php, ajax

If I `console.log` the ID out after I am meant to delete the record, the correct ID displays in console. So, it seems that it is connected up properly but doesn't actually delete a record from my database. I cannot figure this out but it's probably something obvious.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table-row').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $otId = $(this).data('ot-id');
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to undo this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#FB404B',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            closeOnCancel: false
        }, function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'functions/delete-ot-request.php',
                    data: {otId: $otId},
                    success: function (result) {
                        // window.location.href = 'delete-ot.php'; 
                        console.log($otId);
                    },
                });
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Maybe next time then.", "error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['otId'])) {
    $stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM `ot_request` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['otId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

This is the html table row that holds the id:

```
<tr class="table-row" data-ot-id="{$id}"></tr>
```

Comment: can you fully show html code ! Because you posted tr is impossible to click without td

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log($otId);` reports *the id value you previously sent*, not a data coming back from the server side.

Hence this output attests only that *the ajax process* was successful, not the server job, which is likely what turns wrong for some reason.

So you should look for errors at the server side, starting with sending back some execution trace:

```
if(isset($_POST['otId'])) {
  try {
    $stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM `ot_request` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['otId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo 'otId "' . $_POST['otId'] . '" processed';
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage;
  }
} else {
  echo 'No otId found';
}
```

And modifying your Javascript so you output this trace:

```
success: function (result) {
  console.log(result);
}
```